Cannot access EKS cluster via internet with ELB
I have created an EKS cluster via terraform all pods are running as expecting. However, I am having networking challenges. My api-service pod should return hello world when accessing it on port 8000 as such: http://0.0.0.0:8000
I am not very strong with networking and don't even know where to start. I have shared a few screenshots from the instance running one of the pods and the load balancer error warnings.
From the command below, it seems the node port is available on 30000 which is what the ELB wants, isn't it?
kubectl get services -n=simple-app
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
api-service   NodePort    172.20.255.168   <none>        8000:30000/TCP   9h

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Where should I be looking? What questions should I be asking? Why can my load balancer not reach the target group? Where can I check if the ports on the VPC are accessible to the ELB?
Any help would be much appreciated!




you need to check the differents between k8s service type, if you are using a k8s nodePort, that doesn't means that's accessible from outside, you try to change the service type to LoadBalancer, the service will be exposed

Can you please post the security group associated to your EKS cluster. Also via the ELB are you offloading on port 443 to 8000 as in the above screenshot (inbound rules) there is no port 8000 open

It looks like the Load Balancer isn’t able to reach your api-service on port 30000, which is why it’s showing the targets as unhealthy. The first thing I’d check is the security groups. Make sure the EC2 nodes have inbound rules that allow traffic on port 30000 from the Load Balancer, and also confirm that the Load Balancer’s security group allows outbound traffic to the nodes on the same port.
Next, take a look at your VPC setup. If your nodes are in private subnets but the Load Balancer is public, you’ll need to ensure there’s proper routing between the public and private subnets so the Load Balancer can reach your nodes.
Also, check the health check configuration on the Load Balancer. Make sure the path it’s using for health checks (like /api/health) actually exists and is reachable from the Load Balancer.
Lastly, try SSH’ing into one of your nodes and run a curl command to see if you can reach the service on port 30000 locally:
curl http://localhost:30000

If that doesn’t work, there might be an issue with the service or pod itself.
Hope this helps!
